# using prepareforSegue to DetailViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm having problems with the prepareForSegue method to push a DetailViewController.

I've been following many tutorials ok but when I want to use my own data I'm clearly not putting the right thing.

My tableView loads ok with this code, which i then want to pass to a detailviewcontroller when the user selects a blog post.

```
NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://theforeground.co.uk/feed/json"];

NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];

NSError *error = nil;

self.blogPosts = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *blogPostsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];


for (NSDictionary *bpdictionary in blogPostsArray) {
    BlogPost * blogPost = [BlogPost blogPostWithTitle:[bpdictionary
        objectForKey:@"title"]];
    blogPost.excerpt = [bpdictionary objectForKey:@"excerpt"];
    blogPost.thumbnail = [bpdictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    blogPost.date = [bpdictionary objectForKey:@"date"];
    blogPost.content = [bpdictionary objectForKey:@"content"];
    [self.blogPosts addObject:blogPost];
}
```

I have a segue from the tableviewcell to the detailviewcontroller and called it "ShowDetailView" and this is the prepareForeSegue method I was using

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetailView"])
    {
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        BlogPost *blogPost = [self.blogPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
```

I have imported "detailviewcontroller.h" in to "tableviewcontroller.m" and i have these propertys on the detailviewcontroller header file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *blogPosts;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *blogTitle;
```

Please can somebody help this beginner out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You retrieve the data from datasource but you don't pass it to view controller, try that:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetailView"])
    {
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        BlogPost *blogPost = [self.blogPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // You passing the data here to detail view controller
        detailViewController.blogPost = blogPost;

    }
}
```

You also needs to add blogPost property to detailviewcontroller.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) BlogPost *blogPost;
```

After that you can use it, for example in viewDidLoad method in detailviewcontroller.m file.

Comment: Thank you for this, i think thats corrected the prepareForSegue, but it'll continue to crash until i get the viewDidLoad right on the detailviewcontroller.m file. can you help with how it should look? I have IBOutlets for the blog title, image and content to start off with. thank you

Comment: Post the crash log and viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Thanks greg, the error occurs here     `BlogPost *blogPost = [self.blogPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`    
and the viewDidLoad method is `- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];`

Comment: Post error, Is it happened in table view controller or detail view controller?

Comment: the table view works fine, it crashes when i tap to go to the detail view

Comment: It crashes when you type the row in the table view controller or it crashes in viewDidLoad? Where this line comes from BlogPost *blogPost = [self.blogPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; is it from prepareForSegue in TVC? Post error, please.

Comment: thank you greg, my issue is now fixed though.    `[[segue destinationViewController] setPostTitle:blogPost.title];` should have been the last line